# how can i pass a "&" into a querystring value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, request.querystring

i have a link in my app with the following URL:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/test?group=MyGroup
```

the issue is one of the groups is called **Group A & B**

when i try this and parse it on the serverside (through Request.QueryString["Group"])

```
 http://www.mysite.com/test?group=Group A & B
```

i get

group='Group A ' (because of the &)

how can i change my URL so it can deal with values with "&" inside of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method to make your text safe for a querystring.

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/test?group=" + 
           System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("Group A & B");
```